# Recursion example - Python

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm a novice at Python and I'm trying to get to grips with concepts such as recursion.

I'm trying to create a recursive function that takes each element of a list and returns the product of those elements.

I have a non-recursive function that works:

```
elements = [1.1,2.2,3.3,12.12]

def mult1(elements):
    total = 1
    for i in elements:
        total = total * i
    return total
```

I want to be able to compute this function but recursively.

Currently my code for the recursive function is:

```
list = [1,2,3,10]

def mult2(list):
    i = len(list)
    total = 1
    if (i == 0):
        return total
    else:
        total = total * i
        mult2(i-1)
```

I don't get any errors (I'm using Komodo) but it doesn't return a value.
If anyone could explain to me what the issue is that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you need to return the value `mult2(i-1)` with `return mult2(i-1)`

Comment: Also, you initially call mult2 with a list as the parameter, but in the last line you call it with a number as the parameter

Comment: I've changed my code. I'll type it in here. 

list = [1,2,3,4,10]
def mult2(list):
       if not list:
            return 0
       mult2(list[0] * list[1:]).

Got any ideas?